# What is the significance of do-my-work tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

I think we really need to remove this tag.

[do-my-work](/questions/tagged/do-my-work)

Comment: Can you please explain! Why shall we remove it? Why was it introduced?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They were all added sarcastically by the same user. I'm deleting them; it's a shame you can't downvote an edit.

Comment: Actually, there was one instance from a different user (who I quoted in my answer), around the same time Graphain first created the tag last year. Then the tag quieted down until Graphain seems to have gone off-hook on the subject and revitalized it by slapping it on a bunch of questions last month.

Answer (score 8):

The tag appears to have been created, in the same vein as the old [plz-send-teh-codez](/questions/tagged/plz-send-teh-codez), as a derogatory mark used to indicate questions where the asker is showing little effort and is instead just saying "Please do my work for me". While such questions are not an entirely appreciated act, it's not something that warrants a tag. Downvotes suffice for that.

> @Code Sherpa: Your question is "Any kind soul out there willing to convert this for me?" which I believe explains the use of do-my-work tag perfectly. Essentially you want the SO community to do your work. You don't have any specific PHP question to ask, you're just unwilling to learn the language. – Anax Jul 9 '10 at 13:53

I removed what wasn't already taken care of by others just now (like [Wooble](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95402/whats-the-significance-of-do-my-work-tag/95403#95403) and Bill the Lizard, the latter of whom also appears to have done some deletion work).